# Global Variable In a Decorator

Tags: python

I have a decorator called profiled that keeps track of the number of times a function has been called.

```
class profiled(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.__count=0
        self.__f=f
        self.__name__=f.__name__
    def __call__(self,*args,**dargs):
        self.__count+=1
        return self.__f(*args,**dargs)
    def count(self):
        return self.__count
    def reset(self):
        self.__count=0
```

How would I make the count variable global so that when I use profiled with variaous functions, the total count would be stored instead of just the count with a certain function.

Comment: Could you use a python class variable instead of instance variables?

Comment: Couldn't you just...make `count` a global variable?  Although I think a class variable would work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a class attribute, and you need to ensure you never assign to it directly on `self` (which would create an instance attribute shadowing the class attribute). You can do this by changing:

```
class profiled(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.__count=0
        self.__f=f
        self.__name__=f.__name__
    def __call__(self,*args,**dargs):
        self.__count+=1
        return self.__f(*args,**dargs)
    def reset(self):
        self.__count=0
```

to (comments on changes in line):

```
class profiled(object):
    __count=0  # Class attribute shared for all @profiled functions
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.__f=f
        self.__name__=f.__name__
    def __call__(self,*args,**dargs):
        type(self).__count+=1  # Increment __count on the type, not the instance
        return self.__f(*args,**dargs)

    # Use a classmethod here, since we don't need self at all
    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        cls.__count=0
```

The `count` method requires no changes (though you may as well make it a `@classmethod` since no instance specific stuff is involved), because even as an instance method, it's only reading `__count`, not writing it, which won't create an instance attribute to shadow the class attribute, and seamlessly accesses the class attribute.